# Firebase realtime database not working in React native project

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In my react native android project I am using firebase real-time database. When I am trying to save new data in DB, it's not saving. Also it's not even showing any error. I am using below example code in my project:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

let usersRef = firebase.database().ref();

try {
    usersRef.child("users").set({
        alanisawesome: {
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
        },
        gracehop: {
            date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
            full_name: "Grace Hopper"
        }
    }).then((success) => {
        console.log("SUCCESS", success)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR 1", error)
    });
} catch(error) {
    console.log("ERROR 2", error)
}
```

It's not going inside SUCCESS, ERROR 1, or ERROR 2 in the above code. What will be the issue here?

Firebase authentication and firebase storage using the same google package is working fine in this project.

I am using "react-native-firebase" package also in my project, just for notifications.